# Como tratar a permissão de KB por usuário

Tags: genexus

Tenho uma KB que quero habilitar para determinado usuário.

E para outros usuários não quero acesso a esta KB.

Como tratar isto no Genexus Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode definir um ROLE (papel) específico para o usuário dessa KB (isso desde o Tab Security do console principal).

Logo, na parte de segurança dessa KB (tab Security dentro da KB) o administrador pode dar privilégios para esse ROLE (papel) e tirar para os outros papéis.

Comment: A dúvida e foi comprovado é que existe e funciona é que o PAPEL(Role) a nível de KB(Admin, KBuser, Unknow) e configuração de papel por KB(KBUser), ai sim funciona.